# getElementById.contentDocument error in IE

Tags: javascript, explorer, getelementbyid

```
<html>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function func() {
         alert(document.getElementById('iView').contentDocument);
      }    
   </script>
   <body>
      <iframe id="iView" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></iframe>
      <a href="#" onclick="func();">click</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

After click, Firefox returns [object HTMLDocument]. Internet Explorer returns undefined.

How can I select the iView element with Internet Explorer? Thanks.

Comment: @Mauris: he is being polite, and has asked just 10 questions. He'll have time to learn the rules here. Make those comments to those poeple that have asked over 100 questions and have never accepted an anser, or answered a question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23475/should-questions-with-no-accepted-answers-be-punished-after-awhile

Comment: sorry, dont know that this system has 'accept' functionality, thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [this page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ie2mozgd/):

> Mozilla supports the W3C standard of accessing iframe's document object through IFrameElm.contentDocument, while Internet Explorer requires you to access it through document.frames["name"] and then access the resulting document.

So you need to detect the browser and on IE do something like this instead:

```
document.frames['iView'].document;
```

Answer (score 43):

The cross-browser equivalent to `contentDocument` (including Firefox itself, where `contentDocument` *does* work) is `contentWindow.document`.

So try:

```
alert(document.getElementById('iView').contentWindow.document);
```

`contentWindow` gets you a reference to the iframe's `window` object, and of course `.document` is just the DOM Document object for the iframe.

[Here's an article that summarizes better](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs.php).

Comment: worked for me to solve my problem with IE7. newer IE versions seem to support contentDocument.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want to get the contents of the iframe right?

IE7 and FF2:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iView');
alert(iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use feature detection, as `contentDocument` is supported in IE 8:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iView");
var iframeDocument = null;
if (iframe.contentDocument) {
    iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument;
} else if (iframe.contentWindow) {
    // for IE 5.5, 6 and 7:
    iframeDocument = iframe.contentWindow.document;
}
if (!!iframeDocument) {
    // do things with the iframe's document object
} else {
    // this browser doesn't seem to support the iframe document object
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

is working for me in Internet Explorer and Firefox, whereas

```
contentDocument.body.innerHTML
```

will only work in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
var myFrame = document.getElementById('iView');
var frameDoc = myFrame.contentDocument || myFrame.contentWindow;

if (frameDoc.document){
  frameDoc = frameDoc.document;
}

alert(frameDoc);
```

See [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp) for more details