# how to access the "id',"name" etc. of Loaded URL in iframe from the HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  have an Iframe.html file :

```
<body onload="alert('frame 1 loaded');">
<div> This is frame 1 content </div>
<a id="a1" href="Sample.html"> click</a> 
</body>
```

Sample.html

```
<body>
<ul id="list1">
<li name="one">one</li>
<li name="two">two</li>
</ul>
```

And I calling the iframe form test.html file :

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var i=10;
    $("#frame1").ready(function () { 

    $('#frame1').contents().find('#a1').click(function() {
       alert("Hello");
      $('#frame1').attr('src', $('#frame1').contents().find('#a1').attr("href"));
      $('#frame1').load();
    });
    $('#frame1').contents().find('#a1').click(); 
</script>
    </head>
    <body onload="handleMainOnload();">
        <!--iframe id="frame1" src="about:blank"/-->
        <iframe id="frame1" src="iframe.html"/>
    </body>
```

**Now I tried using the content of URL loaded in iframe i.e. Sample.html in test.html as follows :**

```
$('#frame1').contents().find('#list1 li[name=one]').click(function() {
   alert(" Clicking list....");
});

$('#frame1').contents().find('#list1 li[name=one]').click();
```

**But this doesn't work.. Can you please tell me From Test.html how to access Sample.html file content like(id,name,class etc.) which is loaded in iframe.html using JQuery. 
Please help.**

Thanks
Kamakshi

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not quite sure how to do what you are asking, but you should optimize your code.  `var $frame = $('#frame1');` and then use `$frame` to do your actions, such as `$frame.contents().find('#a1').click();`  If you don't, jQuery traverses your document each time to find it.  It's a performance hit you don't want to take.

Comment: Which browser are you using?...Iframes can behave differently in different browser environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Main Frame 2 Title </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
------
------
alert("frame ready");
var $value1 = $frame.contents().find('#list1 li[name=one]').html() ;
alert("loaded + " + $value1);
$frame.contents().find('#list1 li[name=one]').click(function() {
    alert("About + clicked");
}); 
$frame.contents().find('#list1 li[name=one]').click();
 });  });
</script>
</head> 
<body>
 <iframe id="frame1" src="sample.html" />
```

This works fine, if i am giving iframe `src=sample.html` directly instead of redirecting using another file (i.e. `src=iframe.html`) and keeping Sample.html in same domain as parent file (test.html).

Answer (score 0):

To access any document inside an iframe included inside an HTML take for example the following page:

```
<html>
....
<body>
<iframe id='myFrame' name='myFrame' src='someUrl'>
</body>
</html>
```

You can access using the following script

```
myFrame.document.getElementById('elementID');
```

Make sure you provide a **name** (here: myFrame) that is used to access the frame itself.
The elementID is the id of any element inside the html/url loaded inside the iframe

Comment: Using just the name is not optimal. `window.frames["myFrame"]` or `document.getElementsByName("myFrame)[0]`  will get the frame by name, but `document.getElementById('myFrame')` will also get the frame using the provided ID. However the asker has jQuery, so other methods are available

Comment: Well!! if you use the `document.getElementById('myFrame')` you're sure to get the iframe, but you cant access the elements that are loaded inside the iframe...and the asker I think needs to access the elements inside the iframe

Comment: @SM09 Yes you can `document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow.document` and equivalent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477547/getelementbyid-contentdocument-error-in-ie

Comment: Hi, but i am intended to go with JQuery, as i have to write click event for the elements of iframe URL content(Sample.html) in test.html . This is not possible with the normal javascript. Please suggest some solution in JQuery how this can be achievable. This code supports Firefox and IE both. To be more precise how to acces/control/manipulate the content/elements of the URL loaded in any html file using JQUery