# In IE, when binding to the 'load' event of an IFRAME, this.contentDocument is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

Ok, bear with me folks, the setup on this one is long.

I have a simple page. It loads an iframe. Inside that iframe is a form. I want the form inside the iframe to interact with the parent page via jQuery.

This works correctly in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. See for yourself here:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58785/iframe-example/index.htm

However, in Internet Explorer 6/7/8/9, it does not work. The load event fires, but jQuery cannot get a handle on elements inside the iframe.

I'm using the second 'context' argument of the jQuery function to set the context of the selector, like this: `var form = $('#myform'), this.contentDocument)`

**Here's what is batty**. Using the F12 Developer Tools in IE9, I can set a breakpoint in my JavaScript and look at how IE is evaluating the JavaScript. If I hover over `this`, I can see that it does have a `contentDocument` property. **BUT**, if I hover over `this.contentDocument`, it tells me it's undefined.

[image: Shows up as defined]

[image: Shows up as undefined]

Because it's undefined, the jQuery selector returns no elements. Again, this is only in IE. And the IFRAME is on the same domain, so it's not a same-origin issue.

Any pointers?

Comment: Have you tried `contentWindow`? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477547/getelementbyid-contentdocument-error-in-ie

Comment: @Roatin Marth - yes, `this.contentWindow.document` fixes everything. Can you post that as an answer so you can get the rep you rightfully deserve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to trample on Roatin's answer, but this issue can also be fixed by specifying a DOCTYPE declaraction. Internet Explorer 8 and over require it for contentDocument. Otherwise, as he said, contentWindow can be used (for earlier versions of IE, too). See [the information at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp).