# How to get element by id in page contained iframes, frame, frameset?

Tags: javascript, frame

I have a page that contains many children such as `iframe`, `frameset`, `frame` etc.

I would like a function like `document.getElementById(targetId)` that returns an element, but also searches in the documents of all frames.

I would prefer a solution that doesn't require any extentions like jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
my_iframe_reference.contentDocument.getElementById(targetId)
```

to search by id in a single frame.

If you want to search on all the frames you can iterate over the `window.frames` array.

```
for(var i=0; i<window.frames.length; i++){
    var node = window.frames[i].contentDocument.getElementById('id');
    if(node) return node;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i tested it but get this error `contentDocument is undefined`. my browser is ie8

Comment: Try `contentWindow.document` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477547/getelementbyid-contentdocument-error-in-ie

Comment: frames[] only returns an array of `iframes` no `frames`, at least in IE