# <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EDGE"/> generates error

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, angularjs, x-ua-compatible

I am introducing angularjs in my existing ASP.NET project and the project currently supports only IE. When i try to browse the project with angular js, angularjs was not booting up in my browser, IE 9. when i googled about it, i came across a solution to introduce meta tag as

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EDGE"/>
```

But after using the above meta tag, angularjs seems to booting up but now i am getting following error:

```
Unable to get value of the property 'getElementsByTagName': object is null or undefined
```

So, Now i have following questions:

Why am i getting such errors after introducing that meta tag and how to fix it?
why angularjs was not booting without that meta tag? 
when i googled for the solution i found this stackoverflow page:

[getElementsByTagName is null or undefined, only in IE - and only in one particular spot in the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156622/getelementsbytagname-is-null-or-undefined-only-in-ie-and-only-in-one-particul)

But here it says the error is possibly due to incompatible statement used in the project which must be corrected. My current project is a vast project and already in production, now i cannot figure out all possible places to check for incompatible statements and fix them. so how can i successfully introduce angularjs in my existing asp.net project?

Comment: so what happens without meta tag, does page run in quirks mode?

Comment: page runs without issues but angularjs not booting and it throws error as "object does n't support property or method 'queryselector' from angularjs file

Comment: then it sounds like page running in quirks mode. Is it missing a valid `doctype`?  Try running it through W3C validator

Comment: i tried adding html5 doctype <!DOCTYPE html>, but no luck. how can i run it through w3c validator?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: i am not able to do that validation as my portal is not public only clients use them.

Comment: Also i tried disabling SCE from angular js module configuration and removed meta tag. but still angularjs not booting.

Comment: you can paste html from source into validator also. Check if browser in quirks mode, I beleieve it is

Comment: i validated with source it says doctype is XHTML 1.0 Transitional and my IE browser says its in quirks mode.

Comment: so you need to find out what in the page is causing quirks mode. Can't you just create your angular app in standalone page using proper doctype etc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61116/discussion-between-alagesan-palani-and-charlietfl).