# iframe load doesn't work when form submit in IE

Tags: javascript, file, internet-explorer

I'd like to upload a file in IE9, and I used form and iframe. this is my html code:

```
<iframe name="ie9Iframe" ref="iframe" src="" width="0" height="0"></iframe>
<form ref="uploadForm" target="ie9Iframe" action="/pages/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input class="fileChoose" type="file" name="upload_file" @change="fileChanged" id="file"/>
    <input type="submit" value="提交" id="fileSubmit"/>
</form>
```

this is my js to bind onload event:

```
   var iframe = document.getElementsByName('ie9Iframe')[0];
   console.log(iframe.toString());
   if(iframe.attachEvent) {
     console.log('attachevent')
     iframe.attachEvent('onload', function () {
       console.log(11111111111111)
       var responseText = iframe.contentDocument.body.textContent;
       console.log(responseText)
       if(responseText == '') {
           return;
       }
       var responseData = JSON.parse(responseText) || {};
           console.log(22222222222222222222)
           console.log(JSON.stringify(responseData))
           if(responseData.status == 1) {
              this.fileId = responseData.protocol.file_id;
           }
        })
   }else {
        console.log('notAttachevent')
   }
```

and this is my console log:

```
日志: [object HTMLIFrameElement] 
日志: attachevent 
日志: 11111111111111 
日志:
```

when i submit my form, it return some json data but the iframe onload event is not  called, so i can not get the data. i have tried many methods but they did not work.Any suggestions or comments will be great.. THANKS !

Comment: If the image upload is the only action performed by the form you could load the form directly into the iframe, and then the form submit action will be inside the iframe itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `onload` event is executed (you are getting the `111111111` log included inside the `onload` block code. The problem of your script is the code to get the iframe content.

Try this instead:

```
var responseText = iframe.document.body.textContent;
```

You should get the iframe text content in a slightly different way on Internet Explorer. Check the following  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477547/getelementbyid-contentdocument-error-in-ie).